# INSERT INTO mySQL from client side with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to insert data from the Client side to a remote mySQL database

I am calling a function and passing a variable into it.

```
function uploadMetrics(email){
   var email;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'php/insertConvertData.php',
    data: {
        data: {"email" : email },
       //data:email,
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

On the server I have a php file

```
$user = $_POST['email'];
echo $user;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // for viewing it as an array
var_dump($_POST); // for viewing all info of the array
echo '</pre>';


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO cms_conversion_funnel (email)
VALUES ('" . $user . "')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

The code runs fine and I can connect to the database and run the insert but in inserts an empty string.

I dumped out the value of 'email' to the console and got this:

```
(
   [data] => Array
        (
            [email] => teretst@gmail.com
        )

)
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(17) "teretst@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

It seems like there is a value in the email variable but it is not being picked up an passed into the insert statement. Can anyone help, I am new to php and AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's `$_POST['data']['email']`, not `$_POST['email']`.

Comment: But ['data'] is redundant, you don't need to use data: {data :{}}, just use data: {email: email}

Comment: This is true, but the immediate reason this is happening is the wrong $_POST key was being used. Whether that should be resolved by simplifying the $_POST key or by modifying the usage of the key is an exercise left to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data: {"email" : email }`, email is a parameter, you don't have to declare it again:

```
function uploadMetrics(email){          
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'php/insertConvertData.php',
    data: {"email" : email },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are taking the variable email as input and then redeclaring the same email which is again turning it empty. Please remove
Var email.

Next thing you have to fetch as $_POST['data']['email']

Comment: Thank you! As a matter of interest, it worked if I left the var email in and changed the fetch as you described,  $_POST['data']['email'] and it worked then.

Comment: The world is full of surprises :)